# SSL pinning in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, sslpinning, trustkit

How to incorporate SSL pinning in React Native using axios for api calls.

I came across TrustKit but my continues efforts to use the same ends up crashing my app. I tried both the ways of adding TrustKit.

- Via Info.list

```
<key>TSKConfiguration</key>
<dict>
    <key>TSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates</key>
    <true/>
    <key>TSKPinnedDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourDomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>TSKPublicKeyHashes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public key 1</string>
                <string>public key 2</string>
            </array>
            <key>TSKPublicKeyAlgorithms</key>
            <array>
                <string>TSKAlgorithmRsa2048</string>
            </array>
            <key>TSKIncludeSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>TSKEnforcePinning</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

- Via AppDelegate.mm within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
  // Override TrustKit's logger method, useful for local debugging
   void (^loggerBlock)(NSString *) = ^void(NSString *message)
   {
     NSLog(@"TrustKit log: %@", message);
   };
   [TrustKit setLoggerBlock:loggerBlock];

   NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
   @{
     // Swizzling because we can't access the NSURLSession instance used in React Native's fetch method
     kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,
     kTSKPinnedDomains: @{
         @"busdue.com" : @{
             kTSKIncludeSubdomains: @YES, // Pin all subdomains
             kTSKEnforcePinning: @YES, // Block connections if pinning validation failed
             kTSKDisableDefaultReportUri: @YES,
             kTSKPublicKeyHashes : @[
               @"dz0GbS1i4LnBsJwhRw3iuZmVcgqpn+AlxSBRxUbOz0k=",
               @"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=", // Fake backup key but we need to provide 2 pins
             ],
         },
     }};
   [TrustKit initSharedInstanceWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];
   [TrustKit sharedInstance].pinningValidatorCallback = ^(TSKPinningValidatorResult *result, NSString *notedHostname, TKSDomainPinningPolicy *policy) {
     if (result.finalTrustDecision == TSKTrustEvaluationFailedNoMatchingPin) {
       NSLog(@"TrustKit certificate matching failed");
       // Add more logging here. i.e. Sentry, BugSnag etc
     }
   };
```

I always end up getting this crash    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/673OW.png)

Any suggestions are appreciated.